# psql: error: FATAL: database "businesslogic" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker

This is my first question here so please bear with me for a while. I created two postgres users named 'keyloak' and 'businesslogic' with databases named 'keycloak' and 'sumo' respectively. Both users have the same password. After having built the image and run the docker container, I tried to login to each user in the bash terminal with the following commands:

psql -h localhost -U keycloak

psql -h localhost -U businesslogic

I could login to keycloak after having entered the password but could not do so for businesslogic. I got the following error,

psql: error: FATAL:  database "businesslogic" does not exist

After logging into user 'keycloak' I could see, using commands \du and \l, that the two users and the two databases were created. But for some reason I cannot login to user 'businesslogic'. I don't know where I have gone wrong.

I would be glad if anyone can shed some light on this issue. I looked through other similar questions but could not find anything helpful.

If you need further information I will be happy to provide it.

I am sorry I had to delete the code details because of confidentiality reasons. It seems both the user name and the database name have to be the same in order for me to login. I set the database name to be the same as the user name and now I am able to login. It seems pretty strange why that might be the case.

As always any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `psql -h localhost -d keycloak -U businesslogic` See `psql --help` for all the options.. Can you clarify if you are prompted for a password?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and show: - how you created user `businesslogic` and the database `businesslogic` - the command you used to log in to the database.

Comment: _"If you need further information I will be happy to provide it."_ As @Turing85 already stated, show how you created the users, any `ALTER ROLE` you might have set and how you created the db as well as who is the owner of keycloak..

Comment: @iLuvLogix  Thanks for you reply. Yes I am prompted for a password for businesslogic and I can now login. But after I login the name tag says 'keycloak=>' and not 'businesslogic=>'

Comment: Please add relevant/clarifying information to your question (via edit).. Please consider also to add some images/messages (like name-tag) to your question so we can narrow down your isssue..

Comment: Aslo add the version of postgresql you are currently using

Comment: If the database name matches the user/owner name, then I am able to login using
psql -h localhost -U businesslogic. In this case both the database name and user/owner name was businesslogic. But if the names are different, then I have to use the command psql -h localhost -d sumo -U businesslogic. Also in the first case, the prompt becomes businesslogic=>, whcih is the user/owner name. In the second the prompt becomes sumo=>, which is the database name. Anyone know why that is??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`psql -h localhost -d sumo -U businesslogic`.

This error:

`psql: error: FATAL: database "businesslogic" does not exist`

occurred because you did:

`psql -h localhost -U businesslogic`.

In the absence of an explicit database name (`-d sumo`) `psql` will default to using the user name `businesslogic` as the database name and as the error said there is no such name.

See [Key words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adrian. Your command worked. But I want to know why the prompt shows sumo=> , which is the name of the database, and not businesslogic=> , which is the name of the user/owner. 
Another point is I can login using 
psql -h localhost -U businesslogic
if the name of the database and the name of the user/owner are the same. In that case, it shows the prompt businesslogic=> and not sumo=>.
Do you know why that might be??

Comment: Because it is spelled out in the Key Words link I posted in my answer.  As to the prompt read this [Prompting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING).

Comment: Thanks for the documents Adrian. Just want to ask you, is there no way to login without also having to specify the database?? Because if a user has, say 10 or more databases under their name, should they know each one by name in order to login??

Comment: The only way you don't have to specify a database is for the case we have already discussed where the username is the same as the database name. You can a [service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pgservice.html) to keep connection parameters together, but you still have to remember which one applies to which database.

Comment: As always, thank you very much Adrian. Much appreciated.